# Facebook API Error 100 Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted trying to Public Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, fb.ui

Im getting this error when I try to post in a wall via my FBApp, the application used to
work, but yesterday I notice that is throwing this error.

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted.
```

My app is loging the user and everything works, it throw the error trying to post. 
The code that I use to post is this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'My Title',
    link: "http://mysite.com?"+query_string,
    caption: '',
    description: 'My Description'
 },
function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      //alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      //alert('Post was not published.');
    }
});
```

Another thing is that the https domain that im using is a hosting shared ssl:
https://vivaro.websitewelcome.com/~username

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I just had the same problem because I was using an application with underscores in its URL’s subdomain.

I was using:

```
foo_bar_test.rosette.ca/myapp
```

changed it to

```
foobartest.rosette.ca/myapp
```

and I didn’t get the "Error 100" anymore.

Comment: I wrote short blog post with additional info: http://trackingrails.com/posts/why-facebook-is-not-showing-share-dialog-inside-tab